# How to turn off Rubber/Elastic scrolling effect on ipad?

Tags: jquery, html, ios, ipad, mobile

My page carries both vertical and horizontal scrolling , 
Now if user swipes exactly left/right it works perfectly but the problem arise when swipe is not exact i.e. on straight line(diagonally). here both the horizontal and vertical swipe  events gets triggered , vertical swipe slides the page on left or right side while horizontal swipe creates elastic effect on Ipad .

I tried My making window scroll off on the body and applied class on the container where I need the swipe. But it didn't helped in my case.

I tried some css fixes also but failed

As my page has full width layers.

Carousel i am using is carouFredSel.

Carousel works both vertical and horizontal.

I want to achieve that while swiping left elasticity effect of IOS should not happen

Library used   Jquery 1.9.1
For TOuch : Hammer.js

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating  in your page with "overflow-x(or y): auto;". Divisions will probably help.

Comment: I require both x and y axis for my functionality so overflow x and y will not work in this case.